# How to concat 3 dataframes with each into sequential columns

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to understand how to concat three individual dataframes (i.e df1, df2, df3) into a new dataframe say df4 whereby each individual dataframe has its own column left to right order.

I've tried using concat with `axis = 1` to do this, but it appears not possible to automate this with a single action.

```
Table1_updated = pd.DataFrame(columns=['3P','2PG-3Io','3Io'])
Table1_updated=pd.concat([get_table1_3P,get_table1_2P_max_3Io,get_table1_3Io])
```

Note that with the exception of `get_table1_2P_max_3Io`, which has two columns, all other dataframes have one column

For example,

get_table1_3P =

[image]

get_table1_2P_max_3Io =

[image]

get_table1_3Io =

[image]

Ultimately, i would like to see the following:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some data samples to question?

Comment: All data frames have 10 rows in total and all with the exception of one frame having only 1 column

Comment: unfortunately without sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really hard answer, it is only guessing...

Comment: I don't understand *"with each into sequential columns"* or *"whereby each individual dataframe has its own column left to right order"*, but I think you mean *"concat the columns but then reorder/preserve column order from the constituent dataframes"*. Yes, that's a simple column reorder command after the `concat`. Also, please post an example, and there's no reason not to name the columns A,B,C...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need first `concat` and tthen change order by list of columns names:

```
Table1_updated=pd.concat([get_table1_3P,get_table1_2P_max_3Io,get_table1_3Io], axis=1)

Table1_updated = Table1_updated[['3P','2PG-3Io','3Io']]
```